# Microsoft Azure: I have check in the code from the Visual Studio, and it automatically build in the pipeline

Tags: azure, push, clone, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have checked in the code from the Visual Studio, and it automatically builds in the pipeline. Now I want to push that into one of my branches, let's say Dev from where I clone and fixed the necessary updates and bugs. Now I want to replace the old codes in Dev bran with my codes which I already build successfully in the pipeline.
I am a newbie in Azure DevOps. 
PS: It could be really simple/stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a New [`Pull Request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pullrequest?view=azure-devops) to the Branch you want to merge

Say if you want to merge feat_201 to the dev branch. Create a new pull request to the dev branch from the feat_201 branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run below git commands to merge your codes changes from one branch to Dev branch in azure devops.

1,Say you were working on a branch bugfix and fixed the bugs. And you want your azure repo Dev branch to have the code changes. You can run below git commands on your local machine.

```
git fetch
git checkout Dev
git merge bugfix
git push
```

2,To [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) bugfix branch to Dev branch, you can run below git commands.

```
git fetch
git checkout bugfix
git rebase Dev
git checkout Dev
git merge bugfix
git push
```

3,You can also create a pull request to merge one branch to another branch from Web UI Azure Devops Repos page as @Sajeetharan pointed out.

Go your Azure Project -> Repos -> Pull Requests-> New Pull Request(on the right top corner)

[image][image]

Select the source branch and target branch of your pull request.
[image]

Hope above helps.